# Why my drag drop just accept 1 file in c# listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

Below is my code: (Before it works fine, but now just accpeting 1 file to be added at the list)

```
    private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var validExtensions = new[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".JPEG", ".JPG", ".BMP", ".PNG" };
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            if (FirstDrag == true)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                FirstDrag = false;
            }
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Contains(file) == false && validExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: "Before it works fine..." What did you changed?

Comment: did not change anything. . .actually it does not work because the directory length is too long. . .